# How to typecast in Powershell

Tags: powershell

```
function Get-MyClass {    
    return [MyClass]::new()
    # return New-Object MyClass()
}

...
[Object]$myclassObject = Get-MyClass
[MyClass]$myclass = $myclassObject -as [MyClass]
```

This just gives me null - even the `$mytypeObject` is an `[Object]` assigned with the `[MyType]` object?

Comment: What happens when you remove (`-as [MyType]`)? And can you show us exactly how you created/instantiated `$mytypeObject`?

Comment: Thanks, just updated the question

Comment: Why not do `$myClass = [MyClass]$myClassObject`?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the behavior described with the code provided - if I define a class `class MyClass {}` and run your code, `$myclass` is an instance of `[MyClass]` as expected

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen I will try to restructure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it's

```
$a = [datetime]'1/1'
```

-as is similar, but it's more programmable:

```
$type = 'datetime'
$a = '1/1' -as $type
```

On the left side, it also limits that variable to that type, even if it's reassigned:

```
[datetime]$a = '1/1'
$a = 1
```